# How to remap Win+Tab with Alt+Tab in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

Is there a way to replace the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key combination with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Windows 7?

I'd be interested in a way to do so without [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), but if Autohotkey is the only answer please provide the script.

I would like to replace <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as well.

Comment: You may also be interested in an other window switching solution using autohotkey: http://lifehacker.com/5278802/iswitchw-finds-windows-as-you-type

Comment: NOTE TO ANSWERERS: This is much harder than you think.  Simply pointing in the direction of an app or a technique in AHK is not sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

In an [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script you can add the line:

```
LAlt & Tab::Send #{Tab}
```

When the left alt key and Tab are pressed, it will send Win-Tab to the system.

For some reason, I have yet to get the shift key working (if anyone can explain it in a comment, I'll add it!)

<sub>Caveat: I don't have a version of Windows 7 to play with. This was tested on a Windows XP SP3 machine.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

ALT+TAB is a lot more functional in my opinion.

Anyway, I've not used this myself, as I have never had a reason to, but you could try using [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/).

Comment: How is this supposed to work? What I want is to have the functionality that is available with Win+Tab when I press Alt+Tab and the other way round. But the Win key and Alt key should work normaly when pressed separatly. SharpKeys does not seem to able to do that

Comment: SharpKeys 3.5 does not allow you to remap Win+Tab to Alt+Tab... just tried it. As to "ALT+TAB is more functional..." it depends on your use case. I use a Mac most of the day for development, but the family has a Windows machine. So I want to remap the keyboard so that I can use the Win key like the Apple CMD key and avoid constantly  hitting the wrong key combinations.

Comment: @JESii I meant that I find the Alt+Tab task switcher in Windows 7 to be more useful than the Win+Tab 3D task switcher.